Example of ring with exactly one prime ideal not of the form $R/m^n$
In a homework problem, I was asked to find rings $R$ such that $\text{Spec}(R)$ has only a single element, i.e. so that $R$ has only a single prime ideal. $R$ may have zero divisors - otherwise obviously fields are the only possibility.
Everyone more or less managed to think of examples like $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ or $k[X]/(X^2)$ (where $k$ is a field), and the most general example I could find was the quotient ring $S/m^n$ for any ring $S$ and maximal ideal $m \subset S$.
My question is: Are there any examples of such $R$ that are not of the form $S/m^n$ for some $S$ containing more than one prime ideal?
I know the answer is "no" without that last condition since you can just take $S=R$, but have not been able to find an example or a proof of nonexistence with that condition included.
EDIT: To clarify just in case, "ring" is always meant as a ring with $1$.

Note that $R/M^n$ is either a field (in case $n=1$) or else $M$ is a nonzero nilpotent ideal.
Take $R=\mathbb Q[x^{1/2}, x^{1/4},x^{1/8},\ldots]/(x)$.  This is local with a nil, non-nilpotent maximal ideal $M=(x^{1/2}, x^{1/4},x^{1/8},\ldots)$.  In particular $R$ is not a field and its maximal ideal is nonzero and not nilpotent.

DaRT query for other such rings

Ahhh, and I see a place where I was misthinking. I saw "$m=\sqrt{(0)}$" and automatically jumped to "$m^n = (0)$ for some $n$". Obviously not true if $R$ is not finitely generated...
